# Why activity label doesn't appear in App Info?

Tags: android, gomobile, gomobile-android

A strange thing occurs to my app. I set labels for most `AndroidManifest.xml` nodes still my app doesn't get label in App Info activity!

I expect to see "Git Sync" while I see "com.githun.sync" as shown in the screenshots

What's wrong in my `AndroidManifest.xml`?

[image]

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.githun.sync"
    android:label="Git Sync"
    android:versionCode="14"
    android:versionName="14"
    platformBuildVersionCode="30"
>
    <!-- <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26"
    /> -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false"
    />

    <application
        android:label="Git Sync"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:persistent="true"
    >
        <activity
            android:name="org.golang.app.GoNativeActivity"
            android:label="Git Sync"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:label="Git Sync"
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="com.githun.sync"
            />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```